# Issues uploading images to Firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase from the Gallery of the phone but the simulator keeps closing and it's not logging any errors. Here is my code

```
val PICK_IMAGE_CODE=123
fun loadImage(){
    var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_CODE)
}

 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_CODE  && data!=null && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        val selectedImage=data.data
        val filePathColum= arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val cursor= contentResolver.query(selectedImage,filePathColum,null,null,null)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val coulomIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColum[0])
        val picturePath=cursor.getString(coulomIndex)
        cursor.close()
       uploadImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath))
    }


}

var DownloadURL:String?=""

fun uploadImage(bitmap:Bitmap){
    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

    var currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser

    val storage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
   val storgaRef=storage.reference
    val df= SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss")
    val dataobj= Date()
    val imagePath= currentUser!!.uid+ "."+ df.format(dataobj)+ ".jpg"
    val ImageRef=storgaRef.child("imagePost/"+imagePath )
    val baos= ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos)
    val data= baos.toByteArray()
    val uploadTask=ImageRef.putBytes(data)
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener{
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"fail to upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->

        DownloadURL= taskSnapshot.downloadUrl!!.toString()
        ListTweets.removeAt(0)
        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
}
```

If I comment out the call I make to uploadImage the simulator doesn't crash so I think there is something going on with the way I get the picturePath but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I wasn't asking for permissions so the picturePath I was using was always null